# Laravel 4.2 Authentication Success but Redirect kills the session AWS server

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

does anyone here encounter on your laravel app that authentication kills the session after redirect? I have bluehost and aws hosting. bluehost works perfectly but on aws the problem occurs.

Comment: you use file or database session?

Comment: i'm using 'driver' => 'cookie',

Comment: make sure session_cookie enabled in your aws server